# Promise data not returned on device in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I've been pulling my hair out for the last week over this bug so I'm really hoping someone will be able to tell me where I'm going wrong.

I have a ionic app, I'm using PouchDB with the SQLlite cordova plugin. When the app loads if there is any existing data in local storage I'm grabbing it and adding it to PouchDB. This works fine in a desktop browser (Chrome and Safari) and also in the iOS simulator BUT not on a device....

Here's the code that's failing:

```
PouchdbFactory.updateCodes(oldCodesArray).then(function() { // <-- this works, it updates the pouchDB with a reformed array of the old localstorage data

        PouchdbFactory.getAllCodes().then(function(codes) { // Codes is always empty when on the device, but contains all the data in pouchDB when ran in the ios simulator or on desktop chrome/safari
            $scope.codes = codes;
            $rootScope.$emit('codesUpdated', codes);
            $localstorage.removeObject('codes');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error); // I don't get any errors on device
        });
});
```

Heres my service methods:

```
.factory('PouchdbFactory', ['$q', function ($q) {

    var db,
        codes,
        codesPromise;

    var initDB = function() {
        db = new PouchDB('codes', {adapter: 'websql', auto_compaction: true}); //auto_compaction: true
    }

    var deleteDB = function() {
        db.destroy().then(function() { console.log('database destroyed') });
    }

    var addCode = function(code) {
        return $q.when(db.post(code));
    }

    var updateCode = function(code) {
        return $q.when(db.put(code));
    }

    var updateCodes = function(codes) {

        var postPromises = [];

        codes.forEach(function(code) {
            console.log('looping in new updateCodes');
            postPromises.push(addCode(code));
        });

        return $q.all(postPromises);
    }

    var deleteCode = function(code) {
        return $q.when(db.remove(code));
    }

    var findIndex = function(array, id) {
        var low = 0, high = array.length, mid;
        while (low < high) {
            mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            array[mid]._id < id ? low = mid + 1 : high = mid
        }
        return low;
    }

var onDatabaseChange = function(change) {

    console.log('db.changes() has detected a change');

    var index = findIndex(codes, change.id);
    var code = codes[index];

    if (change.deleted) {
        if (code) {
            codes.splice(index, 1); // delete
        }
    } else {
        if (code && code._id === change.id) {
            codes[index] = change.doc; // update
        } else {
            codes.splice(index, 0, change.doc) // insert
        }
    }
}

var getAllCodes = function() {
    if (!codesPromise) {
        codesPromise = $q.when(db.allDocs({ include_docs: true})).then(function(docs) {

            // Each row has a .doc object and we just want to send an
            // array of code objects back to the calling controller,
            // so map the array to contain just the .doc objects.
            codes = docs.rows.map(function(row) {
                return row.doc;
            });

            // Listen for changes on the database.
            db.changes({ live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true}).on('change', onDatabaseChange);

            //Essentially, the call which sets up the changes listener is async. Depending on timing, this means that the documents inserted during the bulk_docs call might be saved before the listener starts.

            return codes;
        });

        return codesPromise;
    } else {

        // Return cached data as a promise
        //return $q.when(codesPromise);

        return codesPromise;
    }
}
return {
        initDB: initDB,
        deleteDB: deleteDB,
        addCode: addCode,
        updateCode: updateCode,
        updateCodes: updateCodes,
        deleteCode: deleteCode,
        getAllCodes: getAllCodes
    }
}])
```

The db gets initialized in the main ionic `.run()` function:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'ngCordova', 'app.services', 'app.filters'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localstorage, $rootScope, $interval, $timeout, OtpFactory, $state, $cordovaGoogleAnalytics, $cordovaSplashscreen, $timeout, PouchdbFactory) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        ... other code ....

        PouchDB.debug.enable('*');
        PouchdbFactory.initDB();
    });
})
```

In case you missed the comments in the code, getAllCodes() should return all the data in the the PouchDB (which it does on the ios simulator and on desktop chrome ad safari) however, codes is always empty when ran on device...

At first I thought this was a pouchDB issue but this only happens when deployed on a device (the data is added to PouchDB fune but the returned codes from getAllCodes() is always empty...

Please can someone help and stop me from getting the noose out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the getAllCodes function, too?

Comment: Added, thanks for looking.

Comment: And you are sure that $q.when returning data inside docs and the db variable is globally accessible?

Comment: Yes, well, it works fine on desktop chrome and safari and on the iOS simulator just not when deployed to a device. Though any additional tips for debugging you can give me would be great, I'm new to Pouch and fairly new to Angular.

Comment: I use gapDebug for debugging on simulator and device. Here is a link:
https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

Can you show where do you initialize your db variable?

Comment: Added more code to the above and I'm downloading the tool you suggested.

Comment: Tried gapDebug, looks like it's just an embedded version of safari remote dev?

Comment: I don't know safari remote dev so it could be true. Well what if you try to use sqlite adapter instead of websql. I had also problems with websql on my ionic projects so I decided to use sqlite only on mobile applications.

Comment: My understanding was as long as the cordova sqllite plugin was present in my project Pouch would pick up on it - http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html. I'll see if there is a why to test.